# java Spring MVC ValidationMessages.properties utf-8

Tags: java, spring, mvc, utf-8

Здравствуйте, нужна помощь с кодировкой `utf-8`
я работаю над проектом `Spring MVC` 
я подключил "бин":

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    <property name="basenames" value="classpath:messages,classpath:ValidationMessages"/>
</bean>
```

Также файлы для локализации

```
messages_ru.properties,
```

файлы для локализации валидации

```
ValidationMessages.properties
```

на странице `jsp` я использую:

```
<spring:message code="firstname"/>
<form:errors path="firstname" cssClass="error"></form:errors>
```

и все прекрасно работает, но есть одна проблема -
все что есть в `ValidationMessages.properties` на русском языке - я получаю на `jsp`:

> Ð²Ð¾Ð»Ð°Ð¾Ð»Ð²Ð¾Ð»Ð°Ð²Ð4

а `с messages_ru.properties` все хорошо отображается на русском.

Это взрывает мозг, в чем проблема? Я "перегуглил" все что можно, также пробовал добавлять "бин" `validator` и делать `ref` на `messageSource` -безуспешно.

Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: У jsp-страницы атрибут pageEncoding указан?

Comment: encoding-filter  org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter

Comment: Попробуйте в начале jsp-файла вставить `<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>`.

Answer (score 2):

1. Прямо в браузере измени кодировку на utf-8 (в хроме значок настроек/дополнительные инструменты/кодировка). Если поможет, добавь в страницу в тег `<head><meta charset="UTF-8"></head>`.
2. Проверь сам файл `ValidationMessages.properties`, в какой кодировке он сохранен, и принудительно сохрани в utf-8.

Answer (score 1):

Это может быть проблема с кодировкой по умолчанию кот зависит от ОС,
попробуй проверить из приложения какая кодировка установлена по умолчанию

```
 System.out.println(Charset.defaultCharset());
```

если это не UTF-8 то добавь параметры запуска для jvm

```
 -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте в web-xml добавить еще один фильтр:
 `<filter>
        <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>`